# Jupyter not rendering latex

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Not sure what's up, but I just noticed my anaconda based jupyter totally fails to render latex.  I don't get an error, but if I put $x$ in a markdown cell, I get back $x$.  Any suggestions on how to diagnose/fix?

Comment: Have you googled? I found `%%latex` and then in the next line but same cell `$x$`

Comment: Doesn't do anything for me, and that's not something I've had to do previously.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I shutdown the server and restarted it, and now it works.  Wish I knew what happened.